# Email marked as spam: Change email hostname used in headers to a real email?

Tags: php, email

I've been having email problems since I changed from shared hosting to VPS at Inmotion Hosting, and the support has been unable to help me. If you can, you deserve a job at Inmotion Hosting =).

When my website sends email using PHP vanilla mail() (booking confirmations etc), all my emails get marked as spam by Microsoft servers (@msn.com, @hotmail.com etc). When I send email through my email client (Thunderbird) or through webmail, all emails go through fine.

Here's the header from email from website (gets marked as spam):

```
x-store-info:4r51+eLowCe79NzwdU2kR0zqpsRfiBoyI3IQ2Zy1UTkQ55b7tRUtzoU6PrUJSFB0oySrjR39TlGfHeGMjzyBE7vAprX1Qut7AjkZmP73XwQ5UhN/wjbganEDSyell12MNjR75URHDeg=
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=none (sender IP is 198.46.84.148) smtp.mailfrom=easter40@secure.easterisland.travel; dkim=none header.d=easterisland.travel; x-hmca=none header.id=info@easterisland.travel
X-SID-PRA: info@easterisland.travel
X-AUTH-Result: NONE
X-SID-Result: NONE
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD02
X-Message-Info: /3z5fcrqMMUMuqyIyKstMXLVq7u60TmAzd6cXJ5ZZxdbQVUetEJ+OG3sb2YlheUWkmyQ4fwnBSKPmOw9vGQj+ZCNhMG6TFxshX0hhpl8AftbwCNagRX7px3mUn+Oy0WbKK6yXLOOVkYGv+BJUQcSQk/+iN1O0wZ/Y1fSs5VIz2duyY0X1Rf6AheX3UJy0pCVctLHeebzg5If1TQ89UdjLKQeXcjeN8LTT9GPhCCFHv4mJlzRg+G7aQ==
Received: from secure.easterisland.travel ([198.46.84.148]) by COL004-MC6F28.hotmail.com over TLS secured channel with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.23143);
     Wed, 3 Feb 2016 12:29:36 -0800
Received: from easter40 by secure.easterisland.travel with local (Exim 4.86)
    (envelope-from <easter40@secure.easterisland.travel>)
    id 1aR43Q-0002xu-GJ; Wed, 03 Feb 2016 15:29:35 -0500
To: m.edensky@live.se
Subject: Booking inquiry sent!
X-PHP-Script: www.easterisland.travel/ajax/sendEmail.php for 186.37.129.249
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
To: Marcus Edensky <m.edensky@live.se>
From: Easter Island Travel <info@easterisland.travel>
Message-Id: <E1aR43Q-0002xu-GJ@secure.easterisland.travel>
Date: Wed, 03 Feb 2016 15:29:32 -0500
X-OutGoing-Spam-Status: No, score=1.7
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - secure.easterisland.travel
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - live.se
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [504 504] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - secure.easterisland.travel
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: secure.easterisland.travel: authenticated_id: easter40/from_h
X-Authenticated-Sender: secure.easterisland.travel: info@easterisland.travel
Return-Path: easter40@secure.easterisland.travel
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 03 Feb 2016 20:29:36.0172 (UTC) FILETIME=[992876C0:01D15EC1]
```

Here's header from email sent through Thunderbird:

```
x-store-info:4r51+eLowCe79NzwdU2kR0zqpsRfiBoyI3IQ2Zy1UTlmiwJyCc7gjkkyPiEHm+iis6y6rzdJPoqrUEDjycuD1moHrvrfMyp8ZOGO72UCPP8gWu+QBmm5PD7Ojol6KtIR1l0GIuB0Aak=
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is 198.46.84.148) smtp.mailfrom=info@easterisland.travel; dkim=pass header.d=easterisland.travel; x-hmca=pass header.id=info@easterisland.travel
X-SID-PRA: info@easterisland.travel
X-AUTH-Result: PASS
X-SID-Result: PASS
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD00
X-Message-Info: /3z5fcrqMMUR0dwt6iqUxJED9hyedMN4CRQ38legRDRBfL6MMv//dM1rcWa1asrgpUQP92eCKmFNkktlyn4QaM+/ZZMWICtPEX8l9M6RQzCqbBUW0GXOFb9dLuVmYKhFytGW9gMHHD5os5zV1yijkU6bu61OMl2xtDrFT4Vkj5my3z6LMITU5JZEpjTDoKocrpOCjCXFAH/qzo7RvFZuH9KiRb4DIRgbQwDIJqTYKP/43UjAnPbq9A==
Received: from secure.easterisland.travel ([198.46.84.148]) by COL004-MC3F42.hotmail.com over TLS secured channel with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.23143);
     Wed, 3 Feb 2016 13:23:15 -0800
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=easterisland.travel; s=default; h=Content-Type:MIME-Version:Date:Message-ID
    :Subject:From:To; bh=k23oFIOL0dvMqR63vfQ+HyAXIsIWIhA8s626IBg0K3I=; b=MwT2zvo8
    MPTcQCghWzsTHA5KxKfUd5FvwlEQfmLVrteaRJY8/aiMx6dANXMLQZ0Qriq5HzDXBJwktWfXJmCgC
    YITekxeMX6uGSJ82CQyQ6s6dE9Cry9JGHsXJ3E1KFyG6LOArEkBCR31BVhoViJvAvdgs/zP6FLLFb
    7EOh5QS8hg0UX+GXOAOyTSSfLN0CJAmJBMrmXzfF9ZqI3F+w7U4BNov+0nRpxqE7NRnv0mHWFutBS
    FQSG7B6FgcA6K0cdPRaSpOvwxxszLZiYoK/CWY6oVUAzTRKpl57UFE9QBE7SWWL83egbHpmBgYuP1
    z6FF3n0Z/RbAYybrQjaQR+XWrw==;
Received: from [186.37.129.249] (port=63085)
    by secure.easterisland.travel with esmtpsa (TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128)
    (Exim 4.86)
    (envelope-from <info@easterisland.travel>)
    id 1aR4tK-00039S-Rr
    for m.edensky@live.se; Wed, 03 Feb 2016 16:23:14 -0500
To: m.edensky@live.se
From: Easter Island Travel <info@easterisland.travel>
Subject: test
Message-ID: <56B26FB5.7090305@easterisland.travel>
Date: Wed, 3 Feb 2016 16:23:01 -0500
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101
 Thunderbird/38.5.1
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="------------020005080507070709050505"
X-OutGoing-Spam-Status: No, score=0.3
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - secure.easterisland.travel
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - live.se
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - easterisland.travel
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: secure.easterisland.travel: authenticated_id: info@easterisland.travel
X-Authenticated-Sender: secure.easterisland.travel: info@easterisland.travel
Return-Path: info@easterisland.travel
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 03 Feb 2016 21:23:15.0570 (UTC) FILETIME=[18119D20:01D15EC9]

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------020005080507070709050505
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=windows-1252; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

As you can see, the spam marked email is using an email address that doesn't exist (easter40@secure.easterisland.travel), and spf + dkim records don't exist (inmotionhosting support tells me it's impossible to apply these records for this hostname).

What you also can see, is that emails that are sent from website (and marked as spam by MS) are sent using hostname easter40@secure.easterisland.travel. I want them to be sent using info@easterisland.travel as hostname instead. This should make emails get delivered, right?

How is this done? php.ini? Any ideas?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

These are the headers I'm using to send all my emails through the website:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: ' . $_POST['name'] . ' <' . $_POST['email'] . '>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Easter Island Travel <info@easterisland.travel>" . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Use a different method to send your email?  See if your server supports SMTP.  Your server may be blacklisted by many recipient servers for abuse.  It's like sending an email from 000webhost.  All their servers are blacklisted.

Comment: Have you tried priority? $headers .= "X-Priority: 1 (Highest)\n";
        $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n";
        $headers .= "Importance: High\n";

Comment: obviously, start using an smtp server that has dkim set up, and don't use mail() (if you are). it's a nearly useless toy for anything "serious". use a proper like phpmailer or swiftmailer.

Comment: if you are using php  I recoment phpmailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the way you are building the email headers in php. It may help to post your sample php code

Comment: Thank you for all your comments! My hosting provider reassured me that the IP wasn't blacklisted before they gave it to me. Also, blacklisting would cause all emails (from webmail and Thunderbird) to be marked as spam as well. I've updated the question with the headers I use in my PHP code. I haven't changed any code though, only server (even within the same hosting company), so server settings must be the problem. What could be wrong with the server settings?

Comment: @ChrisG – Specifying priority is more likely to hurt you than help.  The existence of an `X-Priority` header is twice as common in spam as in legit mail.  `X-MSMail-Priority` is 10x spam:ham.

Comment: You have two `To:` headers.  That might be a problem.  Also, while headers are technically case-insensitive, you should fix the case in your `Content-type` header.  Finally, verify if you need those `\r` characters or not (is this a Windows server?).

Comment: @AdamKatz: Thank you for that info. I had no idea.